# Purpose of time element

Tags: html

I just wanted to know in LAYMAN'S TERMS what can I use the time element for and what is its intended purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to make it possible for a machine reading your HTML to easily interpret a time you put in your code.

For more information, check out http://html5doctor.com/the-time-element/

Answer (score 0):

W3C specfication:
"The time element represents either a time on a 24 hour clock, or a precise date in the proleptic Gregorian calendar, optionally with a time and a time-zone offset.

THe time element appears under the subject of microformats. The main intention of microformats is to make the content on the page available to computers, search engines crawlers and the human user in a standard easily comprehendible manner.

HTML5's new  element presents a huge opportunity to improve the publishing of datetime information on the web

The format: <time>2009-11-13 </time>

Some links to help:
http://speckyboy.com/2011/01/24/beginners-study-guide-to-html5-microformats/

http://html5doctor.com/the-time-element/

http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Time_Element